# How to store transaction response time to a variable in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using transaction controller in jmeter. I want to store the transaction response time to a variable for every loop count. So that i can use that time to make proper test report for each call.
Any suggestion how can i do that?

**Please help. Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1):

By using `Beanshell Listener`, you get a response time of a request.

```
sampleResult.getTime()
```

Instead of creating/updating a report yourself for each call, you can create a report at the end of the test using the JMeter result file.

JMeter can store the result in xml format which will have all the information you would need. Once the test is done, you can apply a stylesheet [check this- https://github.com/auth0/auth0-load-tests/blob/master/reporters/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl] to convert the xml to HTML. It is a nice report with decent information.